# Unable to access the Nexus Repos

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I setup a nexus locally and able to access the UI. I created the required repositories. When i'm trying to access this http://:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/ url, it is throwing 404 error. Attached image for reference. Can someone help me on this.

I configured two more repos with the name of releases and snapshots. Those url's are also throwing the same 404 error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a Nexus 2 style URL, not Nexus 3. 404 is expected in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I added the below line in nexus.properties. org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.HttpBridgeModule.legacy=true  after amending this line I'm able to access the url